# Creating layer depicting area closest to specific polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity

I have a set of oddly shaped and vastly different sized polygons spread across a large area. There are three 'hub' polygons in this feature dataset. I need to figure out which of the hub polygons is closest for all of the other polygons in the feature dataset. distance just needs to measure from the edge of one polygon to another, not the central point. Optimally I need to create an output which maps the boundaries between the three hubs to show at what point the closest hub polygon swaps.

I've tried some different methods with the proximity tools but can't seem to get it working correctly.

Comment: Do you have an advanced license? Tools you will need are Feature Vertices to points and Generate Near Table - both advanced tools, it would be better to separate your hub and other polygons, temporally at least, into two separate feature classes.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes I do have access to an advanced licence.

Comment: Make sure you have a unique id for each polygon. Feature Vertices to Points for the other polygons, Generate Near Table from other vertex points to hub polygons, Summary Statistics on the near table with summary field distance, type of minimum and case field of your unique polygon ID - This will give you a minimum distance to ALL HUB POLYGONS, trim the table down in Excel manually or write a python script, Join by Attributes the trimmed near table to your other polygons and calculate the nearest ID and distance from the table.

Comment: Hi Michael I'm afraid I don't understand, how to I give each polygon a unique ID that will stay with it through the near table generation step? In my workflow I have ensured each polygon has a unique ID, i then convert the polygon vertices to points and each of these points still carries the unique polygon ID, however, once I complete the generate near table I lose the previous unique IDs. I have the unique ID for which hub polygon it is closest to but the near table process only brings in the fid of the vertice point, not the other polygon ID.

Comment: Add a field and call it UniqueID then calculate field to FID or OBJECTID, depending on your datasource, then no matter how you extract/modify the features they will all have a unique ID that matches back to a single dataset. If you have the source FID in the Near Table you can join the table to the vertex points and copy (calculate field) the UniqueID of the originating polygon into the near table, likewise with the near FID, join and calculate the UniqueID from the hub polygons. Be careful you don't edit the features in between as this might reorder the IDs.

Comment: Split datasets in two. Run near on hubs. Use spatial analyst euclidian allocation on hubs to delineate proximity or simply do inverse near.